# snowflake is SaaS but why we need to install snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

snowflake is SaaS but why we need to install snowsql

---

---

---

---

---

Heading

=======

Comment: You don't "need" to install SnowSQL. You can install SnowSQL if you have a use case for the functionality it provides - which is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Snowflake is SaaS, you can use it via a browser and there is no need to install SnowSQL.

SnowSQL is a 'cli' interface targeting users that don't have browser access. E.g. if you are running Linux without GUI, then you will need SnowSQL to use Snowflake.